# JQuery: Trying to disable button if at least one field is in use

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, disabled-input

I'm creating a registration form and I want to validate it and check username and email availability before it allows the user to submit the form, this way I do not need a separate page telling them the errors and making them start over.

The code for checking availability is:

```
function checkUsername() {
$.post('php/availability.php',{username: $('#username').val()}, function(usernamedata){
if(usernamedata.exists){
    $("#username").css('background-image','url(images/in-use.png)');
    $("#username-use").val("inuse");
}else{
    $("#username").css('background-image','none');
    $("#username-use").val("free");
} }, 'JSON'); }
```

The code for checking the email is exactly the same, apart from the obvious differences. It checks the database for matching usernames/emails and sets the value of a hidden field depending on the outcome. The hidden fields are both set to "free" by default.

This is the code that is supposed to disable the register button if either username or email is set to 'inuse'. However, it seems to have a mind of its own and I can't figure out how it is getting to its end result.

```
function buttonCheck() {
var username = $("#username-use").val();
var email = $("#email-use").val();
if(username == "free" && email == "free") {
    $("#registration-send").attr('disabled','disabled');
} 
else {
    $("#registration-send").removeAttr('disabled');
} }
```

It seems to be backwards in its working out, enabling the button when something is 'inuse'. I have tried swapping things around but it doesn't change anything.

checkUsername()/checkEmail() and buttonCheck() are both called together onChange of their associated inputs:

```
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" class="req-string" onChange="checkUsername(); buttonCheck()">
```

Comment: I have a feeling that this could be implemented in a more elegant way with $(x).focus() - 'http://api.jquery.com/focus/'. Have you considered this option?

Comment: Yes, that does look more elegant. Can it be used in a "run function when focus is removed" way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free tip : Embrace the callback functions

```
function checkUsername() {
$.post('php/availability.php',{username: $('#username').val()}, function(usernamedata){
if(usernamedata.exists){
    $("#username").css('background-image','url(images/in-use.png)');
    $("#registration-send").attr('disabled','disabled');
}else{
    $("#username").css('background-image','none');
    $("#registration-send").removeAttr('disabled');
} }, 'JSON'); }
```

You don't need to set some hidden field. The best way is to handle that in your success callback itself.

Also you can write similar code for checking email address atomicity.

UPDATE::

```
var correctUsername=0,correctEmail=0;

function checkUsername() {
$.post('php/availability.php',{username: $('#username').val()}, function(usernamedata){
if(usernamedata.exists){
    $("#username").css('background-image','url(images/in-use.png)');
    $("#registration-send").attr('disabled','disabled');
    correctUsername=0;
}else{
    $("#username").css('background-image','none');
    correctUsername=1;
    if(correctEmail==1){
        $("#registration-send").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
} }, 'JSON'); }
```

Repeat the similar code for email where you will set `correctEmail=1` and `removeAttr` if `correctUsername==1`

Comment: This is what I had before but it only checks itself independently. So if I had a username that was already in use and typed an email that was okay, it would re-enable the button regardless of the username check.

Comment: I think we're getting closer but I can still get the button to re-enable if one of them is still in use. If the last check is okay it will override any that are still invalid.

Comment: on what event are you calling this function?
`keyup` or `focus` or something else
My guess being `keyup`

Comment: Scratch that, I had forgotten to add the correctUsername=0; to the failed check. It works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: just a tip : avoid using  `<input type='hidden'/>` stuff